# How to use the input read from Entry command using StringVar() command as a string in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a Python program with tkinter GUI. I am reading a text from the user and aim to use this text read as an argument for further functions. But these functions require the text to be in "string" data type and not "class method" which occurs if I use the `.get()` function.

I have used the Entry widget command to read and used `StringVar()` as a variable.
I tried `str(content.get)` in the `parse1()` function but this does not work

```
def parse1():

    string1=str(content.get)

    try:
        txt = TextBlob(string1) #TextBlob is a function used for string processing
        for sentence in txt.sentences:
            genQuestion(sentence)       
    except Exception as e:
        raise e

Label(window, text="Text").grid(row=0)
content = StringVar()
e1 = Entry(window, textvariable=content)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
Button(window, text='Quit', command=window.quit).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4)
Button(window, text='ADD', command=parse1).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)
window.mainloop()
```

I expect `content.get()` data type be string by using `str()`. When I try   `string1=str(content.get)` nothing happens and program does not progress further. If I try print(string1) to check I get:

```
<bound method StringVar.get of <tkinter.StringVar object at 0x000001D17418B710>>
```

instead of the text entered which is why I'm thinking using `str()` wont work.
I tried without `str()` and I got:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\Tejas Jambhale\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)   File "C:/Users/Tejas Jambhale/Documents/genquest-master/quest.py", line 165, in parse1
    raise e   File "C:/Users/Tejas Jambhale/Documents/genquest-master/quest.py", line 159, in parse1
    txt = TextBlob(string)   File "C:\Users\Tejas Jambhale\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\textblob\blob.py", line 370, in
__init__
    'must be a string, not {0}'.format(type(text))) TypeError: The \`text\` argument passed to \`__init__(text)\` must be a string, not <class 'method'>
```

which means that string data type is needed as an argument in `TextBlob`. Is there any way for data read from user to be in string data type?

Comment: Change `string1=str(content.get)` to `string1 = content.get()`. The parenthesis are required when using the `get()` method and the results of `get()` are already a string.

Comment: Yes, use `content.get("1.0",END)` to catch the content of an Entry field.

Comment: @Rémy `.get("1.0",END)` is not correct. `content` is a `StringVar` not a textbox. `get()` will suffice. Also for an `Entry` field the correct method is `get(0, "end")` or `get()` not `1.0` as `get(1.0, "end")` is for the Text widget.

Comment: oops, correct! Entry is not Text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this code:

```
string1=str(content.get)
```

In the above, you aren't calling the `get` method, you're simply providing the name. `get` is a method, and like any python method you must use parenthesis to call the function. Also, there's no need to convert it to a string because the `get` method will return a string:

```
string1 = content.get()
```

If you want to call the method on the entry and remove the dependency on the `StringVar`, you can do it in a similar way:

```
string1 = e1.get()
```